# Check doctrine settings in the prod env

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, command

When I execute the command `php bin/console doctrine:ensure-production-settings`

I have this result

```
query Cache uses a non-persistent cache driver, Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache.
```

Can someone explain what is this result and what I have to do?

Comment: Which Symfony version?

Comment: Version: Symfony 3.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This simply means that you have no persistent cache set up for Doctrine queries.  Doctrine uses a cache to convert DQL queries to SQL, so in a production environment it makes sense to cache this and not have to do that same work every time.

See here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/caching.html#query-cache

The function that throws the Exception is here:  https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.5/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Configuration.php#L374

and the code looks like this:

```
if ($queryCacheImpl instanceof ArrayCache) {
    throw ORMException::queryCacheUsesNonPersistentCache($queryCacheImpl);
}
```

What you should look to do is implement a caching mechanism on your production environment, whether it be APC, Memcache, Redis, etc.

Answer (score 1):

in Symfony 3.4 (sample)

1. install php-apcu extension
2. uncomment lines on config_prod.yml

   doctrine:

   ```
   orm:

       metadata_cache_driver: apc

       result_cache_driver: apc

       query_cache_driver: apc
   ```

**and use it without error**